# How to Call Remote .EXE from Android?

Tags: android

I have a .Exe file

That Exe file is present in server . how to call that .exe from android mobile or Tablet

Just want to make a call ...to Run the exe

Answer (score 3):

An idea would be to make an Http request to your server from your Android application with some parameter, for example: `mysite.com?startExe=true`. Now let your server listen for requests, and when appropriate request is received, launch .exe program. The .exe program is launched by the server.